# Why is the second "click" Event not working?

Tags: javascript

maybe someone can help me out with this.
I am a coding beginner and i dont unterstand, why the first version of the code doesnt working.
Maybe ive got not enough background information about the click event.

```
let div = document.createElement("div");
    let text_content = document.createTextNode("Lorem Ipsum");
    let action = 0;
    
    div.appendChild(text_content);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    div.className = "div1";
    
    if (action == 0){
        div.addEventListener("click", () => {    
            document.querySelector(".div1").innerText = "Hello World!";
            action = 1;
        });
    }
    
    if (action == 1){
        div.addEventListener("click", () => {
            document.querySelector(".div1").innerText = "Hallo Welt!";
        });
    }

    // The corrected version
    
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    let text_content = document.createTextNode("Lorem Ipsum");
    let action = 0;
    
    div.appendChild(text_content);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    div.className = "div1";



 div.addEventListener("click", () => {  
     
     if (action == 0){
         document.querySelector(".div1").innerText = "Hello World!";
         action = 1;
     }else if (action == 1){
         document.querySelector(".div1").innerText = "Hallo Welt!";
         action = 0;
     }
 });
```

Comment: An event handler is executed only when an event takes place, i.e. it is fired. In your first snippet `action` will never change while the script is running.

Comment: Depending on what initial value action has, you are _either_ adding a click handler that always sets it to 0, _or_ one that always sets it to 1. Which of those two callback functions you assigned, doesn't _change_ any more later on.

Comment: @Teemu But if i click first on the event,, "action" will be 1. So if i click again, the second if condition must be fullfilled or not?

Comment: @CBroe But why?

Comment: @grotivanhelden — Because things happen at the time you tell them to happen. You're checking the value of `action` to decide which event handler to create. The second event handler is never created because you only change the value of `action` *later*.

Comment: @Quentin Oh thank you, now it makes sense. Thanks to all of you guys